# Probability one instance on an n-dimensional random variable is bigger than another

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

Consider an $N-$dimensional random variable ($X_1,...,X_N$) given by joint density $f(x_1,...,x_n)$. Let $(Y_1,...,Y_N$) be an independent sample from the same joint distribution. What is the probability that $X_i>Y_i$ for all $i=1,...,N$.

In the case of a 1-d variable, this is of course 1/2. In this general case I gather it must depend on $f$ because we can consider two limiting cases:

1. If all the $X_i$ are copies of each other, then this probability is just 1/2
2. If all the $X_i$ are independent of each other, then this probability is (1/2)$^N$

And so these quantities bound the probability. How would I get this as an expression dependent on $f$. Furthermore, what about marginal cases

i.e. what is the probability that $X_1>Y_1$ but $X_2<Y_2$ etc?

Has this problem been studied?
Let me know any ideas or hints.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \int_{-\infty}^{x_1}\cdots \int_{-\infty}^{x_n} \, f_Y(y_1, \dots, y_N)\, dy\, f_X(x_1, \dots, x_n)\, dx$.

Comment: What is $f_X$ and $f_Y$, they look like marginals but that doesnt make sense? Thanks